# Show custom post type randomly in any page

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to show random posts from a custom post type in my page. For example, I have 10 posts, but I want to show 5 post in page which will change randomly.

How can I do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom query to get some random posts for your template. The simplest possible solution will be this query:

```
<?php
// Set the post type here, and sort them randomly
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR-POST-TYPE',
    'posts_per_page'=> 5, 
    'order_by' => 'rand',
);
// Initiate a custom query
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
// If the query has any post, start the loop
if($my_query->have_posts()){
    while($my_query->have_posts()){
        // Output a link and a thumbnail of the post
        $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="random-post">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>"/>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
        </div><?php
    }
} ?>
```

Replace `YOUR-POST-TYPE` with your actual post type's name, then paste this code wherever you wish in your template. You can add or remove any element that you wish, if you are familiar with WordPress's functions.

Answer (score 0):

A quick 'googles' turns up several possibilities (the googles are your friend to get answers for most questions).

There is this article http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-random-post-in-wordpress/ .

Plus there are various plugins that will do similar.

I found lots of answers with a quick googles of 'wordpress random posts'.